# Cannot send the same request message multiple times using Func<HttpRequestMessage>

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Our API has retry logic for calling another endpoint. But it kept giving me an error of

> The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request
>   message multiple times

Here's my code

```
public async Task<object> GetResponse()
{
    var httpRequestMessage = ConstructHttpRequestForBatchUpdate(batchRequest, client, requestUri);
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => httpRequestMessage, client, maxRetryValue);
}

private HttpRequestMessage ConstructHttpRequestForBatchUpdate(JArray batchRequest, HttpClient client, Uri requestUri)
{
    var batchReqStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchRequest);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(batchReqStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Put,
        RequestUri = requestUri
    };
    return httpRequestMessage;
}


public class RetryHttpRequest : IRetryHttpRequest
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(Func<HttpRequestMessage> requestMessage, HttpClient client, int maxTryValue)
    {
        var remainingTries = maxTryValue;
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        do
        {
            --remainingTries;
            try
            {
                return await ExecuteSingleAsync(requestMessage(), client);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }
        while (remainingTries > 0);
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteSingleAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return httpResponseMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                var exception = new InvalidOperationException();
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpException)
        {
            throw httpException;
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding, `Func<HttpRequestMessage>` allows it to create a new instance of `HttpRequestMessage`. For example, for this line of code

```
return await ExecuteSingleAsync(requestMessage(), client);
```

`requestMessage()` is creating a new instance for every loop. But if my understanding is correct, i am not sure why it is still giving me this error of sending the same request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `requestMessage()` is creating a new instance for every loop.

This is not the case - the Func you handed in is `() => httpRequestMessage`, which always returns the same instance.

Try this instead:

```
_retryHttpRequest.ExecuteAsync(() => ConstructHttpRequestForBatchUpdate(batchRequest, client, requestUri), client, maxRetryValue);
```